# How come I can install app store profile signed application on my device?

Tags: ios, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

As per my understanding, to create an IPA for distribution for testing or sharing with others, I need to sign my application with AdHoc profile. For uploading the IPA to App Store, I need to sign the application using App Store Distribution profile.

But I have an application for which even if I create an IPA with the App Store distribution profile, I can install it on my test device (no it is not jail broken and yes it has the AdHoc Profile installed on the device). This particular profile was created during iOS 6.

Now when I create a new App Store distribution profile and I try to install on the test device with the AdHoc profile being present I am unable to do so.

Any idea as to how is it possible? Technically as per my understand App Store Distribution profile signed IPA should never be possible to be installed on devices directly using iTunes. It has to be installed through App Store (after Apple's approval).

Comment: I found a similar question link. But after going through it, am getting a bit confused. Can we install App Store builds on the device which contain s the AdHoc provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do so. Somehow the old certificate allowed me to install the app in one of the device, after renewing the certificate it no longer allows me to install the app signed with the appstore certificate in the device.

So the final answer is that, it is not possible. It can only be installed on jailbroken devices (which is a different question altogether).